# How ubuntu manage dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, dependencies, virtualenv

I just have started using Ubuntu due to the requirement of work. But I notice that, when we install a package with apt, apt-get, or conda, it automatically downloads and installs dependencies of the package. Sometimes, I see that it also downloads another version of an already installed package like NumPy or python. So, how could apt or ubuntu separate the dependencies environment of each package and install many versions of some basic packages just for the dependencies purpose? And moreover, how can I separate or manually do this because I usually install unfamous GitHub projects that require very tricky dependencies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First at all ask only one question, not more.

And about dependencies - they are described in to the packages. This is true not only for `deb` packages but also for `rpm`. You have definitions like:

```
Package: mutt
Version: 1.3.17-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.1), default-mta | mail-transport-agent
```

and so on.